# How to get string from several double quotes in a line?

Tags: java, regex, string

Basically, I need to get `a b c` (separately)

from a line (with any amount of spaces between each "

```
"a" "b" "c"
```

Is it possible to do this using string.split?

I've tried everything from `split(".*?\".*?")` to `("\\s*\"\\s*")`.

The latter works, but it splits the data into every other index of the array (1, 3, 5) with the other ones being empty ""

**Edit:**

I'd like for this to apply with any amount/variation of characters, not just a, b and c. (example: `"apple"     "pie"      "dog boy"`)

Found a solution for my specific problem (might not be most efficient):

```
Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
for loop
{
      input = abc.nextLine();
      Scanner in= new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*\"\\s*");
      assign to appropriate index in array using in.next();
      in.next(); to avoid the spaces
}
```

Comment: Also you want your output to be `a b c` not `"a"   "b"    "c"` correct?

Comment: @brso05 I've tried everything from split(".*?\".*?") to ("\\s*\"\\s*"). The latter works, but it splits the data into every other index of the array (1, 3, 5) with the other ones being empty "".

Comment: Looks like you want to [replace all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) " with empty strings

Comment: @brso05 Correct, no quotation marks.

Comment: What if you pattern matched on `\"([a-z])\"`?

Comment: @RobinTopper the appropriate method would be replace(). You don't need a regexp to replace a single character, or even a static substring.

Comment: @RobinTopper Well I considered that, but my intention is to save everything inside a double quote into a different index of the array.

Comment: @cricket_007 That stored everything into the first index (including the \s)

Comment: @randnane you need to combine both methods: split on the space, then remove the quotes from ever string in the array.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem with that is that the things inside the quote can include spaces.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry.

Comment: you can check my 3rd solution @randnane you can use it in case you have spaces between quotes

Comment: @YCF_L The thing that confuses me in the solution is the inclusion of the \'s within the string. With my problem, the user enters the text.

Comment: what did you mean @randnane ?

Comment: @YCF_L String str = "\"a\" \"b\" \"c\" \"\""; These back slashes I don't understand specifically.

Comment: this is just an example @randnane to use " in String you have to use backslash to escape it get it?

Comment: @YCF_L Ah I misunderstood that somehow. Is there absolutely no way to do it via split or useDelimiter?

Comment: I think I've figured out a way using useDelimiter

Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: @randnane it is complicated if you try to use split, i think the better choice is to use Pattern

Answer (score 6):

You can use pattern instead :

```
String str = "\"a\" \"b\" \"c\" \"\"";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\"[a-z]+\"");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group());
}
```

For inputs like this `"a" "b" "c" ""` then the :

**Output**

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

---

If you want to get a b c without quotes you can use :

```
String str = "\"a\" \"b\" \"c\" \"\"";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\"([a-z]+)\"");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
a
b
c
```

---

## String with spaces

If you can have spaces between quotes you can use `\"([a-z\\s]+)\"`

```
String str = "\"a\" \"b\" \"c include spaces \" \"\"";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\"([a-z\\s]+)\"");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
a
b
c include spaces
```

## Ideone

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a replacement first before you split the string, eg "a"   "b" "c" to "a" "b" "c". `String myLetters[] = myString.replaceAll("\\s*"," ").split(" ")` should work through two steps:

1. Replace any run of spaces [`\s*`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with a single space
2. [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the string into pieces based on the single space